# Constructing a PRG from a pseudorandom function

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

I have recently understood how we can construct a pseudorandom function from a PRG. However, I would like to prove the reverse - how can I construct a PRG from a PRF?

Comment: This direction is a bit easier. As a hint: think of what is the distribution of a PRF key with a random key and evaluated at $n$ distinct points.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go through the section 4.4.4 of the book titled "A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography" written by Boneh. In this section, the PRG is constructed by this way:

$G(k):=(F(k,x_1),...,F(k,x_l))$

where $G(\cdot)$ is a PRG, and $F(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a PRF.

Therefore, we can prove that: If F is a secure PRF, then the PRG $G$ described above is a secure PRG.